# How can I add favourite tags to the Stack Overflow app?

Tags: discussion, android-app

How can I add favourite tags to the Stack Overflow Android app, so that I can get specific feeds from the tags that I like. For example, how can I add tags like [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), so that I can get all the favourite tag questions at one place?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Questions asking about how SO works belong on [meta].

Comment: Related question on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244795/android-app-favorite-tags).